# How to print the value changed through the NumberAnimation on console?

Tags: qt, qml, qt-quick

```
import QtQuick 1.0

Rectangle 
{
   id: rect
   width: 100; height: 100
   color: "red"
   property int hh:0

   Text
   {
     text: hh
   }

   MouseArea 
   {
    anchors.fill: parent

    onPressed:
    {
        animation.start()
        console.log(hh)
    }

    NumberAnimation 
    { 
        id: animation
        target: rect
        property: "hh"
        to: 50; 
        duration: 1000 
    }
  }
}
```

Nothing gets printed on the console. **I know that the `hh` is getting changed but I want to see its printed value on the console at the same time. What to do about it?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your value hh is correclty displayed on console in fact, but only one time, when mouse is pressed. So at the first time it will print 0 (as the animation has not change the value and is asynchron), and 50 all the other times.

If you want to print all the intermediate values of `hh`, just handle change signal on this property :

```
import QtQuick 1.0

Rectangle 
{
   id: rect
   width: 100; height: 100
   color: "red"
   property int hh:0

   Text
   {
     text: hh
   }

   MouseArea 
   {
    anchors.fill: parent

    onPressed:
    {
        animation.start()
        console.log(hh)
    }

    NumberAnimation 
    { 
        id: animation
        target: rect
        property: "hh"
        to: 50; 
        duration: 1000 
    }
  }

  onHhChanged: console.log(hh)
}
```

For completeness, note the **camelize** syntax convention used for defining automatically a signal handle on a custom property.